# Windows command to index a web site?

Tags: html, windows, indexing

I need to send someone a simple command to index his static web site, which currently is just a bunch of web pages with no index in the home page.

Is there a native Windows command that he could run in a DOS box and simply copy/paste the output into the HTML home page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as i know.

You can use wget to download the complete contents of a website.  On windows that would be wget for windows (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

With wget you can crawl through the site and use this information to build your index.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had in mind, but does wget create a ready-to-use index file, or would he have to edit the file before pasting it into his homepage?

Comment: no, wget creates no ready-to-use index file, there is no software that does that (as far as i know).  but you can write a powershell script that uses wget to retrieve all the paths of the website and write them in correct HTML format to a HTML file.  after the script has run, he just has to upload the file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.